# Install pl/sh on a postgres-alpine container

Tags: postgresql, alpine-linux

I have a postgres server running in docker container from the image `postgres:9.6-alpine`. I want to write a postgres function that executes some sh commands. For that i want to declare the language plsh like in the function below:

```sql
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION func2 (var1 text) RETURNS text AS '
#!/bin/bash
 touch /home/postgres/$1;
' LANGUAGE plsh;
commit;
```

I do not have the language installed as it is an external project for postgres. Is there a way to install it on alpine?
Here is the link to the [repo](https://github.com/petere/plsh).

Comment: You'd have to build it from source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. `plsh` postgres extension should be built from [source](https://github.com/petere/plsh#installation).

The `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM postgres:9.6-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache git g++ make
RUN git clone https://github.com/petere/plsh && \
    cd plsh && \
    make && \
    make install
```

Answer (score 0):

This `Dockerfile` is for PostgreSQL13

```
FROM postgres:13-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache git g++ make clang llvm10
RUN git clone https://github.com/petere/plsh && \
    cd plsh &&   \
    make &&      \
    make install
```

Build image `docker build --tag plsh:13 .`

Spin a container and test it

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plsh;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hello (who TEXT) RETURNS text
LANGUAGE plsh
AS $$
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello, $1 !"
return 0;
$$;

SELECT hello(who:='world');
```